# Setting proxies in HtmlUnit

Tags: java, http, proxy, htmlunit, socks

I'm using proxies with htmlunit, my proxy list contain mixture of both http and socks, I dont know if the next selected proxy to be passed to htmlunit is type http or socks, will htmlunit automatically determine the type and use the appropriate rule for connecting through that proxy?

Answer (score 1):

I've made an application which used mixture of proxies as well, but it was a while ago. In that version of HtmlUnit, it required being explicitly told if the proxy was SOCKS or not, otherwise it assumed it was a HTTP proxy. I looked briefly in the change logs, and found nothing indicating that this had changed, so the answer should be no, it will assume that the proxy is HTTP if you don't tell HtmlUnit that the proxy is SOCKS.

To check what type a proxy is, one can use something like:

```
SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress("proxyAddress", port);
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, addr); //or Proxy.Type.SOCKS
URL url = new URL("http://google.com");
URConnection conn = url.openConnection(proxy);
```

If the code fails (i.e throws an exception), then the proxy is most likely either dead or SOCKS. (HtmlUnit will throw an exception in the first case anyway, or you can perform the same test again with Proxy.Type.SOCKS if you aren't certain the proxy is alive.)

Comment: Do you know how to check proxy type prior to using it with htmlunit?

Comment: I only know the trial and error way; testing both. I will append an example to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Java Networking and Proxies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html).

It talks about multiple strategies for setting proxies. It also gives option to provide multipe proxy to same connection through proxy selector.

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers are about how to generically use a proxy in a Java program, but it is a little bit different with HtmlUnit.  Setting the proxy on the Java process does nothing; instead you want the simulated browser to use the proxy.

```
int myProxyPort=8080;
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER_8, "myproxyhost.com", myProxyPort);
```

Answer (score 0):

This framework detects the proxy type for you and can instantiate a HtmlUnit WebClient with correct Socks/Http/Https proxy configuration for you: https://github.com/subes/invesdwin-webproxy

Essentially it automates the trial&error approach when maintaining its proxy list for you. So you don't have to worry about that in your own code.